# Read local csv file by FileReader, pass to d3.csvParse

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js, filereader

I was trying to use JavaScript and D3.js to:

1. read a local .csv file from front end
2. pass the data to D3.js for visualization

the .csv file looks like below:

```
time,psi
1,210
2,220
3,400
```

The script file follows:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" accept=".csv" multiple>
<script>
  document.getElementById("fileInput").addEventListener('change', function getFile(){

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload =function fileReadCompleted(){
     console.log(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(this.files[0]);

    const text = reader.result;
    var res = d3.csvParse(text);
    console.log(res);

});
</script>
```

`console.log(reader.result);` shows that I could read in the file.

`typeof reader.result` returns `string`

but when I try to pass the string `reader.result` to `d3.csvParse`, nothing shows up in the console.

Does anyone knows how to pass FileReader result to d3.csvParse for processing?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**:
The code was revised to

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" accept=".csv" multiple>
<script>
  document.getElementById("fileInput").addEventListener('change', function getFile(){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    var res;
    reader.onload =function fileReadCompleted(){
      res = d3.csvParse(reader.result);
      console.log(res);
    };
    reader.readAsText(this.files[0]);
    console.log(res);
});
</script>
```

The first `console.log(res)` shows the objects array.

The second `console.log(res)` outside the `fileReadCompleted` function shows `undefined`.

Just wondering does the data could only be accessed inside the `fileReadCompleted` function?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you have to move the `d3.csvParse` code inside `fileReadCompleted()` function instead.

Comment: Thanks @JoeyChong. Just wondering if the data in `reader.result` could only be accessed within the `fileReadCompleted` function following the `onload`? Or could be accessed outside the function?

Comment: `readAsText` is asynchronous function, that why you need to assign a function to `onload`. The second `console.log(res)` shows `undefined` because `reader` have not finished read the file yet.